# model can't parse string with group separator to long type

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, number-formatting

I think this should be very easy but it puzzled me for 2 days.

I use jquery.numberformatter-1.2.3.min.js to format and parse user input.

```
$("#Qty").blur(function () { 
    $(this).parseNumber({ format: "#,###", 
                          locale: "us" }); 
    $(this).formatNumber({ format: "#,###", 
                           locale: "us" }); 
});
```

I have a model field to show on the view

```
[Required]        
public long? Qty { get; set; }

<div class="display-field">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Qty)</div>
```

however, when use enters "243,000", the mvc3 controller action always thinks it's invalid long.

I tried to use data annotation format attribute and no luck.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#,###}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

How can I get MVC to automatically format the user input in my action and get model state valid ?

It seems the jQuery numberformatter stop the default MVC model formatter to interpret the string.

Comment: This might be a locale issue. Instead of a comma, try using a dot for decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#Qty").blur(function () { 
    $(this).parseNumber({ format: "#.###", 
                          locale: "us" }); 
    $(this).formatNumber({ format: "#.###", 
                           locale: "us" }); 
});

[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:#.###}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

This might be a locale issue. If this fixes your problem let me know and we'll go from there.

Comment: thansk for your reply.  I tried us or au and both get qty = 0 and modelState invalid. I wonder the js library i use prevents the normal MVC format process.